# A new entity was found through the relationship that was not configured to cascade persist operations for entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

In my project I have 2 tables Devis and DetailsDevis they are both link with a ManyToOne Mapping
Devis :

```php
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     */
    private $devis_admin;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\DetailsDevis", mappedBy="devis_id", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $devis_id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", inversedBy="utilisateur_id")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $utilisateur_id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $intitule_devis;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $periodicite;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="blob", nullable=true)
     */
    private $rappel_du_besoin;
```

And my DetailsDevis entity :

```php
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $quantite;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="decimal", precision=9, scale=2)
     */
    private $prix_vente;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="decimal", precision=5, scale=2)
     */
    private $taxe_vente;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Devis", inversedBy="devis_id", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $devis_id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Produit", mappedBy="detailsDevis")
     */
    private $produits;
```

In one of my controller I want to instantiate a new devis Object, I did this :

```php
 $devis = (new Devis())
                ->setDevisAdmin(0)
                ->setUtilisateurId($this->getUser());
            $this->entityManagerInterface->persist($devis);
            $this->entityManagerInterface->flush();
```

But when I try to run the code the following error appear :

> A new entity was found through the relationship
> 'App\Entity\Produit#detailsDevis' that was not configured to cascade
> persist operations for entity:
> App\Entity\DetailsDevis@000000006abb04ea000000001f58b5a5. To solve
> this issue: Either explicitly call EntityManager#persist() on this
> unknown entity or configure cascade persist this association in the
> mapping for example @ManyToOne(..,cascade={"persist"}). If you cannot
> find out which entity causes the problem implement
> 'App\Entity\DetailsDevis#__toString()' to get a clue.

The fact is `DetailsDevis` already have a  `cascade={"persist"}` association Mapping.

The message also told me that create a `__toString()`, could help me to find a clue. But I don't know on what I need to return to create a this toString most of my informations on the table are decimal or relation... Did someone have an idea about what to do ?
THank you.

Comment: Use `@ManyToOne` and `@OneToMany` for the relation Devis/DetailsDevis, see the [doc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/associations.html#mapping-the-manytoone-relationship) and add `cascade={'persist'}` into the annotation ManyToOne

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer, I'm not sure to understand, You think that modified my entity relation can resolve the problem ? I will not have the same problem with differents relations ?

Comment: Your ManyToOne relation is not defined as it should be. (See the link in my 1st comment). You should have `@ManyToOne` in  Devis class and `@OneToMany` in DetailsDevis class, and not `@ManyToOne` in both.

Comment: Thanks I've tried to remapped as you said, but I still have the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

Change `persist` to `merge`. worked for me

```
`$devis = (new Devis())
            ->setDevisAdmin(0)
            ->setUtilisateurId($this->getUser());
        $this->entityManagerInterface->merge($devis);
        $this->entityManagerInterface->flush();`
```

Comment: could you explain why merge works and persist doesn't?